# Getting error as Object [object global] has no method 'searchQuery'

Tags: knockout.js

May I know when the following code is working well in online  examples but not locally. I am using knockout 3.0

```
 var searchModel = {
        searchQuery: ko.observable(''),
        searchHandle: ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var search = this.searchQuery().toLowerCase();
            //return ko.utils.arrayFilter(beers, function (beer) {
            //    return beer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
            //});
            console.log(search);
        }, searchModel)
    }; <input data-bind="value: searchModel.searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" />
```

Comment: Can you point to one online example where this code works?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work as you expect.

```
var searchModel = {
    searchQuery: ko.observable(''),   
};

searchModel.searchHandle = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
    var search = this.searchQuery().toLowerCase();
    //return ko.utils.arrayFilter(beers, function (beer) {
    //    return beer.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
    //});
    console.log(search);
}, searchModel)
```

Also the same here: http://jsfiddle.net/39nCH/12/